# Insert two or more values at once from not related tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert at once, all values from one table's column, with max value of another table, these tables are not connected with each other.

Let's simplify it to the maximum, `tableA` consists of

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
```

`tableB` consist of

```
id
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

`TableC` is

```
 id, external_id
```

Following query definitely is not going to work but I have no other idea how to solve it

`INSERT INTO tablec (id, external_ids)
values
((SELECT max(id) from tablea), (select id from tableb))`

Of course manually inserting max value is not a solution (like `select 101, id from tableb`)

Extected result should be

```
id, external_id
5, 10
5, 11
5, 12
5, 13
5, 14
5, 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tablec (id, external_ids)
select (SELECT max(id) from tablea), id 
from tableb;
```